Unable to Access FastAPI Server on Same Network Using Static IP, Works on External Network
I am running a FastAPI server on a Mac Mini, which has a static IP and a private IP address, and I’ve configured port forwarding on my Jio router. Here are the details of my setup:

Server Details:

FastAPI server running on a Mac Mini on port 8000
Private IP of the Mac Mini: 192.168.29.201
Static IP for external access (assigned by my ISP)


Network Access:

From external networks (different network), I can access the FastAPI server by visiting {static_ip}:8000/docs
From local network, I can access the server using {private_ip}:8000/docs


Issue:
When I try to access the FastAPI server from within the same local network using the static IP ({static_ip}:8000/docs), I receive an error: Site not found. The request does not reach the server.

Troubleshooting:

I have set up port forwarding correctly on my Jio router.
My router does not support NAT loopback or hairpin.



Question:
Is there a way to access my FastAPI server using the static IP address while on the same local network, given that NAT loopback is not available on my router? Or is there any workaround that would allow me to simulate access to the server as if I were on an external network?
Any advice on alternative configurations or potential workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Troubleshooting:

I have set up port forwarding correctly on my Jio router.
My router does not support NAT loopback or hairpin



